# Remove duplicate rows based on field in a select query with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Considering the table `mdl_files` that contains the following fields: `id`, `contenthash`, `timecreated`, `filesize`.

This tables stores attachment files.

We consider that all the rows with the same content hash are duplicate rows and I just want to keep the oldest row (or first if dates are equals).
How can I do that?

The following query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  contenthash,
  filesize,
  to_timestamp(timecreated) :: DATE
FROM mdl_files
ORDER BY contenthash;
```

returns:

```
2480229 00002e87605311feb82b70473b61e81f0223c774    18178   2016-10-05
2997411 0000bfd20ef84948eee6811ce5bbac03de42ccb0    1293    2017-03-31
1304839 000280169fc78d704a2d4569bfb6f42ea4a1d5ae    8203    2015-11-10
1364656 000280169fc78d704a2d4569bfb6f42ea4a1d5ae    8203    2015-11-17
71568   0003c6aec5835964870902d697c06d21abf76bf7    139439  2013-04-19
2959945 000419c19d77df7285e669614075b47414e3ab2c    398 2017-03-20
3483049 00061dc0bc2452304107ddc75e7ee2908c729905    28618   2017-08-17
3483047 00061dc0bc2452304107ddc75e7ee2908c729905    28618   2017-08-17
```

I want to get this resultset:

```
2480229 00002e87605311feb82b70473b61e81f0223c774    18178   2016-10-05
2997411 0000bfd20ef84948eee6811ce5bbac03de42ccb0    1293    2017-03-31
1304839 000280169fc78d704a2d4569bfb6f42ea4a1d5ae    8203    2015-11-10

71568   0003c6aec5835964870902d697c06d21abf76bf7    139439  2013-04-19
2959945 000419c19d77df7285e669614075b47414e3ab2c    398 2017-03-20
3483049 00061dc0bc2452304107ddc75e7ee2908c729905    28618   2017-08-17
```

I want the following duplicated lines to be removed from the resultset:

```
1364656 000280169fc78d704a2d4569bfb6f42ea4a1d5ae    8203    2015-11-17
3483047 00061dc0bc2452304107ddc75e7ee2908c729905    28618   2017-08-17
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (contenthash)
  id,
  contenthash,
  filesize,
  to_timestamp(timecreated) :: DATE
FROM mdl_files
ORDER BY contenthash, timecreated, id;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension that makes sure that returns one row for each unique combination of the keys in parentheses.  The specific row is the first one found based on the `order by` clause.

Comment: exactly what was needed! I will keep this `DISTINCT ON` clause in mind! thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER()` with *windows function* to make row number then delete it.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (
SELECT
      id,
      contenthash,
      filesize,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contenthash,filesize order by timecreated) rn
FROM mdl_files
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/301ac/2)

If you want to `DELETE` duplicate data you can use `EXISTS` in where clause.

```
DELETE 
FROM mdl_files f WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (
  SELECT
        id,
        contenthash,
        filesize,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contenthash,filesize order by timecreated) rn
  FROM mdl_files
  ) t
  where t.rn > 1 and t.id = f.id
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1465/1)

Comment: the select answer with ROW_NUMBER() works fine! thanks.