# SQL remove rows by duplicates in the specified column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data like this below,

```
id,username,whatevermorecolumns
1,cat,more data here..
2,kitty,..
3,cat,..
4,kitten,..
```

and want to remove the rows that has duplicated username. so I expect a result like this

```
id,username,whatevermorecolumns
1,cat,more data here..
2,kitty,..
4,kitten,..
```

There is a problem which, id 1 or 3, should be removed, maybe, I would love to know that also, but what I'm trying to do is count() the rows after filtering the select result, so not a big problem here.

I googled and read some stackoverflow posts, tried "group by" and "distinct" stuff but still have no good idea about this. maybe because it's postgresql? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `DISTINCT ON`?

A similar case to yours on Stack Overflow: [sql - Remove duplicate rows based on field in a select query with PostgreSQL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593281/remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-field-in-a-select-query-with-postgresql)

Example:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (username) id, username, whatevermorecolumns 
from table
where ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct on should do the job

| id | username | whatevermorecolumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat | more data here.. |
| 2 | kitty,.. |  |
| 3 | cat,.. |  |
| 4 | kitten,.. |  |

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (username)
  id,
  username,
  whatevermorecolumns,
FROM tablename;
```

DISTINCT ON will ensure you get one row for an unique key combination which is specified in the paranthesis ( line 1 of code).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *remove* the rows, then you can modify the table using `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where t.id > (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.username = t.username);
```

This removes all but the row with the smallest `id`.

If you just want a result set with no duplicates, then the other answers recommending `distinct on` are the right answer.